# Paypal with escrow In nodejs

Tags: node.js, paypal, escrow

I am trying to integrate Paypal with Escrow in Nodejs app, But unable to find the way how can I do this.
Please suggest!!

Comment: did you find any solution..?

Comment: @usama you can use paypal adaptive payment. It have the same implementation like the escrow one.

Comment: Thanks so its mean we hold funds with the paypal adaptive payments right until the project is not clear.

Comment: @usama Yes, we can.

Comment: can you please let me know how are your sending payments to the receiver because i think the paypal adaptive payments api can hold funds only till 90 days so if you can guide me on this area then it will be very appreciated. 
Thanks again.